# Victory Native (React Native) - VictoryLine - change line color when y value is out of limits

Tags: react-native, victory-charts, victory-native

I'm trying to draw a line chart with high and low limits.
I need to change the line color when y value above the high limit or below the low limit.
This is the result I want to achieve:

[image]

any ideas?

thanks